# How do I override this method in Kotlin (works in Java but not in Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I am using a Calendar widget for my [android (Kotlin) project](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView).

I need to code the `onDayClick()` listener in Kotlin so I can know what day the user selects.

According to the example code in the github page. To do this,  the code goes as follows:

```
compactCalendarView.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {
                toolbar.setTitle(dateFormatForMonth.format(dateClicked));
                List<Event> bookingsFromMap = compactCalendarView.getEvents(dateClicked);
                Log.d(TAG, "inside onclick " + dateFormatForDisplaying.format(dateClicked));
                if (bookingsFromMap != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, bookingsFromMap.toString());
                    mutableBookings.clear();
                    for (Event booking : bookingsFromMap) {
                        mutableBookings.add((String) booking.getData());
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

The method I need to override is written as an interface in the Calendar Library:

```
public class CompactCalendarView extends View {

    public interface CompactCalendarViewListener {
        public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked);
        public void onMonthScroll(Date firstDayOfNewMonth);
    }
```

I can't make this code work in Kotlin. If I copy/paste this code, android studio offers to convert the code, but it still doesn't work.

How can I override this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kotlin, you will create anonymous object whenever you want to implement some callback. In your case, kotlin code will be:-

```
CompactCalendarView().setListener( object: CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener {
  override fun onDayClick(dateClicked: Date?) {
    // write your code here
  }

  override fun onMonthScroll(firstDayOfNewMonth: Date?) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is the solution that i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
compactCalendarView.setListener(object :CompactCalendarView.setListener{
 override fun onDayClick{
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way-:

```
 compactCalendarView.setListener(object : CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
            fun onDayClick(dateClicked: Date) {
                toolbar.setTitle(dateFormatForMonth.format(dateClicked))
                val bookingsFromMap = compactCalendarView.getEvents(dateClicked)
                Log.d(FragmentActivity.TAG, "inside onclick " + dateFormatForDisplaying.format(dateClicked))
                if (bookingsFromMap != null) {
                    Log.d(FragmentActivity.TAG, bookingsFromMap!!.toString())
                    mutableBookings.clear()
                    for (booking in bookingsFromMap!!) {
                        mutableBookings.add(booking.getData() as String)
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        })
```